# почему пустая строка не возвращает boolean?

Tags: javascript

```js
let perrg ='';
console.log(perrg ?? 'random');
console.log(typeof perrg ?? 'random');
```

начал учить js, столкнулся с проблемой. почему пустая строка в этом коде возвращает string, если по сути, она эквивалентна false?

`let perrg =''; console.log(perrg ?? 'random'); console.log(typeof perrg ?? 'random');`

Answer (score 1):

Оператор нулевого слияния (??) это логический оператор, который возвращает значение правого операнда когда значение левого операнда равно null или undefined, в противном случае будет возвращено значение левого операнда.

Пустая строка, как и `false` это не `null` и не `undefined`.

Comment: так, если чтобы получить undifined мне нужно по-просту не присваивать значение переменной, то как конкретно в этом примере получить тип данных null? (вопрос просто для понимания как и что работает, ибо только начал учить)

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar Вы можете использовать `perrg || 'random'`, тогда Ваша логика будет сохранена. Пустая строка будет преобразована в false, тогда выведется представленное fallback значение

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar вместо  `??`  надо использовать `||` в таком случае

Answer (score 0):

В данной ситуации возвращает `string` потому что **Оператор нулевого слияния (??)** не приводит значения к булевому типу.

> Если левое значение (а это пустая строка `''`) является **null** или **undefined** оно возвращает правое значение (это `random`). Но пустая строка не равна **null** или **undefined** .

```js
let perrg ='';
console.log(perrg ?? 'random');
console.log(typeof perrg ?? 'random');
```

Возможно вы путаете с **Условным оператором "?"**

`let result = условие ? значение1 : значение2;`

Если условие выполняется  -  значение 1, не выполняется - значение 2.